# Understanding 形容詞+くも

Tags: grammar

> 色素の薄い髪に、白い簡易霊装。**可愛らしくも**どことなく生意気さが窺えるその顔立ちは、疑似精霊<二ベルコル>に似ているような気がした。

I don’t understand the grammar phenomenon of 形容詞+くも. Could you please explain that? Is it a fixed grammar pattern?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The も in your example 「可愛らしくも...」 is a 接続助詞(conjunctive particle)「も」. From [デジタル大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%82%82/#jn-218351):

> も
> 2⃣［接助］形容詞・形容詞型活用語の連用形、動詞・動詞型活用語の連体形に付く。逆接の意を表す。…とも。…ても。…けれども。「見たくも見られない」「努力するも報われなかった」

It can attach to the continuative form (連用形) of i-adjectives and the attributive form (連体形) of verbs, and mean 「～とも」「～ても」「～けれども」 "even though~~" "~~but".

So your example:

> 可愛らし**くも**どことなく生意気さが窺える

can be rephrased as:

> 可愛らしい**けれども**どことなく生意気さが窺える

This usage of 「～～くも」 sounds pretty literary.

A few examples:

> 「美し**くも**[儚]{はかな}い」"beautiful, but ephemeral"
> 「[微笑]{ほほえ}まし**くも**[切]{せつ}ない」"heartwarming, but sad"