# も after dictionary form of a verb

Tags: grammar, particles, manga, particle-も

[image: Komi C9]

From Komi-san, volume 1, page 61. I understand the second sentence to be "after that, he asked several people, but got the same kind of response, and now he's like this"

But what on earth is this も doing after かける? Is it some grammar point I'm missing or maybe something else?

Comment: Related: [Understanding 形容詞+くも](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/86963/41067)

Comment: aguijonazo's post answers my question. I dont actually know how to close my question, so I flagged it as a duplicate...